# Need help in a wpf application using mef

Tags: wpf, mvvm, mef

I am making an application in wpf following MVVM pattern. I need to add MEF into it.

Here is the basic architecture of my program.

I have a main project MefApplication. This has only one view MainWindow.xaml. This contains one listbox and a user control. When application runs it loads modules and list them down in the listbox. On clicking a module results in displaying module in the usercontrol.

Now for module, it is a WPF User Control Library. Now this module will contain different views. One a view there will be button which will be used to navigate to other views within a module.

Now I have loaded modules and listed them down. On clicking a module results in displaying first screen of a module. But when I click next button on the view of a module nothing happens. I dont know how to go to next view. Below is my code. Can anybody tells me where I am going wrong.

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="MefApplication.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="40*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="80*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ListBox x:Name="listBox" Grid.Column="0" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Modules}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedModule, Mode=TwoWay}" >
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ModuleName}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
    <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding UserInterface}"/>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
    }
}
```

MainWindowViewModel.cs

```
class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region NotifyOfPropertyChanged
    #endregion

    private string _path = "Path to Modules Dll Folder"; 
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        Modules = GetModules(_path);
        SelectedModule = Modules[0];
    }

    public List<IMainModule> GetModules(string path)
    {
        var directoryCatalog = new DirectoryCatalog(path);
        var container = new CompositionContainer(directoryCatalog);
        var modules = container.GetExportedValues<IMainModule>().ToList();
        return modules;
    }

    private IMainModule selectedModule;

    public List<IMainModule> Modules { get; set; }

    public IMainModule SelectedModule
    {
        get { return selectedModule; }
        set
        {
            if (value != selectedModule)
            {
                selectedModule = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange("SelectedModule");
                NotifyOfPropertyChange("UserInterface");
            }
        }
    }

    public UserControl UserInterface
    {
        get
        {
            if (SelectedModule == null)
                return null;
            return SelectedModule.UserInterface;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the Module Interface. It contains module name and its starting view.

```
public interface IMainModule
{
    string Name { get; }
    UserControl UserInterface { get; }
}
```

This is one of my module. ServerWindowModule. This returns UserControl of one of my views in the module (ServerWindow).

```
[Export(typeof(IMainModule))]
class ServerWindowModule : IMainModule
{
    public string Name
    {
        get { return "Server Module"; }
    }

    public UserControl _userInterface { get; set; }
    public UserControl UserInterface
    {
        get { return _userInterface ?? (_userInterface = new ServerWindowView()); }
    }
}
```

This is one of my view. ServerWindowView.

```
public partial class ServerWindowView : UserControl
{
    public ServerWindowView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new ServerWindowViewModel();
    }
}
```

Now here is ViewModel for ServerWindowViewModel.

```
publicclassServerWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region NotifyOfPropertyChanged
    #endregionpublic ServerWindowViewModel()
    {
        LabelText = "Constructor set this.";
    }

    publicstring LabelText { get; set; }

    privateICommand _nextCommand;
    publicICommand NextCommand
    {
        get { return _nextCommand ?? (_nextCommand = newRelayCommand(NextFunction)); }
    }

    public void NextFunction()
    {
        LabelText = "Button set this.";
        NotifyOfPropertyChange("LabelText");
        // TODO: Navigate to ServerValidation View
        // Here i want to go to my next view(ServerValidationView). What should I write here.
    }
}
```

Now on Next button function what should I do that replaces current view to ServerValidationView.

If there are any confusion then please ask.

Thanks,

Comment: post relevant xaml for `MainWindow.xaml`

Comment: @jberger you can find it in question. I have edited it.

Comment: `ContentPresenter` and `ContentControl` can sometimes stifle me.  Did you try `ContentControl`?  When `ListBox.SelectedItem` changes, does the `MainWindowViewModel.UserInterface` property get hit?  Finally, I'd recommend NOT using a `UserControl` in your `IMainModule`.  Instead, for each type implementing `IMainModule`, define a `DataTemplate` in your View.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently doing something similar. I am not sure if this would be the correct way to handle it but my design is that each module would have its own Shell.

For example, the first view of your server window would be a Shell which has a content presenter.  To change a view within a module I would change the content on the presenter within the module.

This is a wild guess based on what I saw from http://www.ra-design.at/silverlight/mediaowl/

Comment: i have a wpf user control library project containing several views (user controls) i want to navigate thorugh these by button event.

Answer (score 0):

[Caliburn.Micro](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/) can help you with this or the framework Rob Eisenberg presented on Mix. It uses dependency property

```
public static class View
{
    public static DependencyProperty ModelProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "Model",
            typeof(object),
            typeof(View),
            new PropertyMetadata(ModelChanged)
            );

    public static void SetModel(DependencyObject d, object value)
    {
        d.SetValue(ModelProperty, value);
    }

    public static object GetModel(DependencyObject d)
    {
        return d.GetValue(ModelProperty);
    }

    public static void ModelChanged(object sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.NewValue == null || args.NewValue == args.OldValue)
            return;

        var vm = args.NewValue as IYourModuleProvidingUI;
        var view = vm.UserInterface;

        ((ContentControl)sender).Content = view;
    }
}
```

And usage

```
<ContentControl Framework:View.Model="{Binding SelectedModule}" Padding="2,0,0,2"/>
```

`SelectedViewModel` is a property raising `INotifyPropertyChanged` event when its value has changed. So what will be displayed is controlled by the value of the SelectedModule property.